# How to provide base classes to autowire in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'd like to write some base classes that should be picked by default to autowire with `Spring`.  Only *if* these classes are extended, thus a custom implementation is provided for them, I want the custom implementation to be picked up, instead of the default one.

How can I achieve it when I don't want to make my default classes `abstract` (as the application should be able to run without custom implementations, just by the default ones)?

The the following example: I want to provide a basic handler for any errors. But this setup would only work if I make the `BaseHandler` abstract, which I don't want (as in this case I would force anyone using my library to implement the class).

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class BaseHandler {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public A_Stadisdatensatz handle(Message<MessageHandlingException> message) {
        process(message.getPayload());
    }

    /**
     * Override to supply specific processing
     */
    void process(Payload payload) {
        //do some default processing
    }
}


@MessageEndpoint
public class CustomHandler extends BaseHandler {
    @Override
    void process(Payload payload) {
        //custom processing
    }
}
```

If I run it this way, `CustomHandler` will never be picked up.
So, is it impossible?

Comment: You might want to look at Spring Profiles. These allow you to create specific beans for specific configuration (dev, prod, ..). See [this blog post](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/) or [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles)

Comment: Hm, I know spring profiles, but I don't think it really suits me needs. I just would like to achieve a binding where by default a default class is wired, and if an extension to this is provided, chose this instead.

Comment: Maybe you need something like @Conditional... annotations of Spring Boot? See http://www.grails.info/2013/09/20/contributing-to-spring-boot-with-a-pull-request/ for an example.

Comment: Can you show us where you are trying to inject it? And how bean configurations are manageD?

Comment: It's not injected anywhere. It's picked up by `@EnableIntegration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose that you are using `@Autowired` to inject the dependencies. In that case you could use `@Primary` annotation to override defaults ones, ie

```
@Primary
@MessageEndpoint
public class CustomHandler extends BaseHandler {
    @Override
    void process(Payload payload) {
        //custom processing
    }
}
```